How far can double 2x8s span as girders/beams for a shed?
I'm getting ready to put up a 10x8 plastic (resin) shed, and I'm planning to use 12-inch concrete piers as the foundation.
I'd like to just do 4 piers, one at each corner, with double 2x8s spanning the long ends, acting as girders/beams. Then add 2x8 joists at 16-inch spacing to span the 8-foot gap, making up the floor (with plywood atop).
Is that too much weight for the beams across the 10-foot span? Should I add 2 more piers in the middle of that span?
Note I've found a few calculators and charts online, but they all seem to focus on single joist spacing. I'm not too worried about the joists as those are only spanning 8 feet or so. I'm concerned about the double 2x8 beams spanning 10 feet, while supporting all the joists in between that will be hanging on them.

In my opinion, it will handle a light floor load, but if you put a riding lawn mower in there or use it for wood storage, no. If you have plywood siding or subsiding and tie the floor system to the walls by means of the plywood. That will increase its strength.

you can look at the prescriptive deck building guide - it goes into beams and joists hanging off beams.  https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/AWC-DCA62012-DeckGuide-1405.pdf

so table 3a says that if you want joist spans at 8' then you'll need (2) 2x12s for a 10' beam span for southern pine beam.  For SPF beam then you'd need (3) 2x10s with a max beam span of 10' 2".  a deck design for a shed floor might be overkill - depends what you are storing in there and how bouncy you want it.

Thanks @FreshCodemonger, I think I'll go with the double 2x12, better safe than sorry. I don't want to have to worry if I get a riding mower in 5 years or something. Also I had the terminology wrong, I thought it was referred to as a girder

It would be just fine with doubled 2x8 beams. I've built enough structures from treehouse platforms to handicap access ramps to million dollar homes (in 2005 money) to know this without a doubt. If you doubt it, go ahead and test it out. Set a pair in place and do your worst. I don't think you'll have any concern once you feel it. Good lumber doesn't break without bending a bunch first.
Residential load tables don't really apply. This is a yard shed, after all, with no life or limb underneath. The only things that matter are utility and appearance.
You may feel a bit of bounce if you try, but it'll be plenty strong. It'll carry the mower and your other junk without issue. Just be sure to select quality boards with small knots for the beams. Crown everything upward. Use 3/4" floor sheathing to further spread load.

Thanks @isherwood - one additional question, I was going to use joist hangers to affix the joists to the beams. But looking at pics of the hangers, they seem to need to run underneath the joist to cradle it. Does that mean I still need to be using bigger beams, like at least 2x10? Or is it okay for that cradle part to be hanging/floating underneath the 2x8 beam?

There's no undermounting with a standard hanger. They'll work as intended on a beam that's the same size as the joist.

Ok great that's exactly what I ordered, I thought from the pic that the bottom extended below the 8-inches of the joist. Thanks again :)

It should wrap the joist snugly. A good strategy is to tack the joist in place with a toenail, then install the hanger.
